# How do I add time in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, cron

I want to create a cron job that will run once in either 30 min or 60 min from now. I know I can grab the time of now by using: date +"%T" but I'm not sure how to add 30 or 60 min to that, and then use it in a cron job.

Comment: Cron jobs are for things you want to run in regular intervals. To run something just once, have a look at the [`at`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html) command.

Comment: `date +"%T" -d "+1 hour"`

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've tried sudo echo "pfctl -d" | at now +60 minute but that didn't work either. Nothing happened after the wait time. I've tried +1 minute as I didn't want to waste a full hour

Comment: @Buraq: you probably need to move the `sudo` into the string being echoed and have it set up so it doesn't need a password: `echo "sudo pfctl -d" | at now +60 minutes`

Comment: @BenjaminW.
The at command is not working on terminal as it fails for: System Policy: deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/at/spool/a0004c018d03a3
I've changed owner of spool to root but still no go

Comment: Also, they way I'm planning to use a Cron Job only once is to delete it after it's done. I know "at" would be more appropriate for this task, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **quick-and-dirty** way to execute a task 30 minutes from now:

```
# (30 min = 1800 sec)
nohup bash -c 'sleep 1800; echo "Hello world"';
```

Or, if you want to execute it 30 minutes from now, and again 60 minutes from now, then:

```
nohup bash -c 'sleep 1800; echo "Hello world"; sleep 3600; echo "Hello world"' &
```

Note emphasis on **quick-and-dirty**

Comment: Like you said, it's dirty and could break easily. I'm looking for something mo robust really. Thanks